# Как получить значения параметров device_id, iid, openudid со своего устройства?

Tags: android

Для работы скрипта с github необходимы значения device_id,iid,openudid

device_id смог узнать с помощью приложения для android, остальное не понятно как извлечь, вообще не понял что это.
Возможно вы знаете как получить значения iid и openudid?

Спасибо!

[github](https://github.com/snuzi/tiktok-scraper-php)

> Use this scraper
>   In order to use and make requests to Tiktok API, some extra device parameters are needed. These parameters should be extracted from your mobile phone by using a man in the middle proxy. I used PacketCapture for Android, you may use any proxy application you like. Grab the following parameters: device_id,iid,openudid.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class OpenUDID_manager implements ServiceConnection {
    final static String PREF_KEY = "openudid";
    final static String PREFS_NAME = "openudid_prefs";

    private final Context mContext; //Application context
    private List<ResolveInfo> mMatchingIntents; //List of available OpenUDID Intents
    private final Map<String, Integer> mReceivedOpenUDIDs; //Map of OpenUDIDs found so far

    private final SharedPreferences mPreferences; //Preferences to store the OpenUDID
    private final Random mRandom;

    private OpenUDID_manager(Context context) {
        mPreferences =  context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mContext = context;
        mRandom = new Random();
        mReceivedOpenUDIDs = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        //Get the OpenUDID from the remote service
        try {
            //Send a random number to the service
            android.os.Parcel data = android.os.Parcel.obtain(); 
            data.writeInt(mRandom.nextInt());
            android.os.Parcel reply = android.os.Parcel.obtain(); 
            service.transact(1, android.os.Parcel.obtain(), reply, 0);
            if (data.readInt() == reply.readInt()) //Check if the service returns us this number
            {
                final String _openUDID = reply.readString();
                if (_openUDID != null) { //if valid OpenUDID, save it
                    if (mReceivedOpenUDIDs.containsKey(_openUDID)) mReceivedOpenUDIDs.put(_openUDID, mReceivedOpenUDIDs.get(_openUDID) + 1);
                    else mReceivedOpenUDIDs.put(_openUDID, 1);

                }
            }
        } catch (RemoteException ignored) {}
        mContext.unbindService(this);
        startService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {}

    @SuppressLint("ApplySharedPref")
    private void storeOpenUDID() {
        mPreferences.edit().putString(PREF_KEY, OpenUDID).commit();
    }

    /*
     * Generate a new OpenUDID
     */
    private void generateOpenUDID() {
        //Try to get the ANDROID_ID
        OpenUDID = Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        if (OpenUDID == null || OpenUDID.equals("9774d56d682e549c") || OpenUDID.length() < 15 ) {
            //if ANDROID_ID is null, or it's equals to the GalaxyTab generic ANDROID_ID or bad, generates a new one
            final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
            OpenUDID = new BigInteger(64, random).toString(16);
        }
    }


    /*
     * Start the oldest service
     */
    private void startService() {
        if (mMatchingIntents.size() > 0) { //There are some Intents untested
            final ServiceInfo servInfo = mMatchingIntents.get(0).serviceInfo;
            final Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setComponent(new ComponentName(servInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, servInfo.name));
            mMatchingIntents.remove(0);
            try {   // try added by Lionscribe
                mContext.bindService(i, this,  Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            }
            catch (SecurityException e) {
                startService(); // ignore this one, and start next one
            }
        } else { //No more service to test

            getMostFrequentOpenUDID(); //Choose the most frequent

            if (OpenUDID == null) //No OpenUDID was chosen, generate one            
                generateOpenUDID();

            storeOpenUDID();//Store it locally
            mInitialized = true;
        }
    }

    private void getMostFrequentOpenUDID() {
        if (!mReceivedOpenUDIDs.isEmpty()) {
            final TreeMap<String,Integer> sorted_OpenUDIDS = new TreeMap(new ValueComparator());
            sorted_OpenUDIDS.putAll(mReceivedOpenUDIDs);
            OpenUDID = sorted_OpenUDIDS.firstKey();
        }
    }

    private static String OpenUDID = null;
    private static boolean mInitialized = false;

    public static String getDeviceID() {
        return OpenUDID_manager.isInitialized() ? OpenUDID_manager.getOpenUDID() : "";
    }

    /**
     * The Method to call to get OpenUDID
     * @return the OpenUDID
     */
    private static String getOpenUDID() {
        return OpenUDID;
    }

    /**
     * The Method to call to get OpenUDID
     * @return the OpenUDID
     */
    private static boolean isInitialized() {
        return mInitialized;
    }

    /**
     * The Method the call at the setMode of your app
     * @param context   you current context
     */
    public static void sync(Context context) {
        //Initialise the Manager
        OpenUDID_manager manager = new OpenUDID_manager(context);

        //Try to get the openudid from local preferences
        OpenUDID = manager.mPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY, null);
        if (OpenUDID == null) //Not found
        {
            //Get the list of all OpenUDID services available (including itself)
            manager.mMatchingIntents = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(new Intent("org.OpenUDID.GETUDID"), 0);

            if (manager.mMatchingIntents != null)
                //Start services one by one
                manager.startService();

        } else {//Got it, you can now call getOpenUDID()
            mInitialized = true;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Used to sort the OpenUDIDs collected by occurrence
     */
    private class ValueComparator implements Comparator {
        public int compare(Object a, Object b) {

            if(mReceivedOpenUDIDs.get(a) < mReceivedOpenUDIDs.get(b)) {
                return 1;
            } else if(mReceivedOpenUDIDs.get(a) == mReceivedOpenUDIDs.get(b)) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
         }
    }
}
```

```
public class OpenUDID_service extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return new  Binder() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTransact(int code, android.os.Parcel data, android.os.Parcel reply, int flags) {
                final SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(OpenUDID_manager.PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                reply.writeInt(data.readInt()); //Return to the sender the input random number
                reply.writeString(preferences.getString(OpenUDID_manager.PREF_KEY, null));
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Добавить в манифест

```
<service android:name=".util.openUDID.OpenUDID_service">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="org.openudid.GETUDID" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Так получаем udid

```
String udid = OpenUDID_manager.getDeviceID();
```